# usr/bin appears empty

Tags: directory, filenames, directory-structure

I'm trying to make a program (Thunderbird) run at startup, but when I go to `usr/bin` it seems empty. However, if I run `$ which Thunderbird` in terminal, it tells me `/usr/bin/thunderbird`.

The `usr/bin` folder has the option to display hidden files checked. What could be the reason I can't find any files in that folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are typing in `/usr/bin`, not `usr/bin`.

The latter means "look for `usr/bin` starting in the current directory." For example, if your current directory is your home directory (`~`), then it will look for `~/usr/bin`.

The former means "look for `/usr/bin` starting from the root directory." This makes sure that the search for `usr/bin` starts from the root directory `/`.

To put this another way, if the path doesn't start with a `/`, then it is assumed that the path you specified is from the current directory.

Comment: `usr/bin` is also called a *relative path* as it is relative to the directory you're in.  On the other hand, `/usr/bin` is an *absolute path*.